# Error trying to lock vm in Azure

Tags: azure, locking, azure-powershell

**I'm using this command:**

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "labservertest1lock" -ResourceName "labservertest1" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/"

**I'm getting this error:**

New-AzureRmResourceLock : ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/labservertest1'
under resource group '' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "labservertest1lock" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceLock], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzur
   eResourceLockCmdlet

**My Resource here:**

Name              : labservertest1
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/276866f0-eb22-4696-9667-2f30d2801a3a/resourceGroups/altqalab/providers/Microsoft.Cla
                    ssicCompute/virtualMachines/labservertest1
ResourceName      : labservertest1
ResourceType      : Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines
ResourceGroupName : altqalab
Location          : westeurope
SubscriptionId    : 276866f0-eb22-4696-9667-2f30d2801a3a

**It seems to be a problem on the ResourseType Flag, what should be my ResourceType for a VM???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because you're not specifying the `ResourceGroupName` parameter (based on the error message)

```
New-AzureRmResourceLock : ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/labservertest1' under resource group '' was not found.
```

Please try the following and see if that works:

```
New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName "labservertest1lock" -ResourceName "labservertest1" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/" -ResourceGroupName "altqalab"
```